# php escaping brackets characters parse error

Tags: php

I think I have to escape `{` as I am gettting error
so here it is

```
function aq_field_icon_picker($field_id, $block_id, $icon, $default = '') {
    $output = '<div class="icon-picker" data-pickerid="fa" data-iconsets='{"fa":"Pick FontAwesome"}'>'; 
    return $output;
}
```

How can I escape {} ?

Comment: What error are you getting? The problem is not the `{` but rather the unescaped `'`s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the ' characters around the {}

```
function aq_field_icon_picker($field_id, $block_id, $icon, $default = '') {
    $output = '<div class="icon-picker" data-pickerid="fa" data-iconsets=\'{"fa":"Pick FontAwesome"}\'>'; 
    return $output;
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php

or change the ' to "

```
function aq_field_icon_picker($field_id, $block_id, $icon, $default = '') {
    $output = '<div class="icon-picker" data-pickerid="fa" data-iconsets="{"fa":"Pick FontAwesome"}">'; 
    return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are ending the string with the single quotes have you tried using double quotes instead

```
$output = '<div class="icon-picker" data-pickerid="fa" data-iconsets="{"fa":"Pick FontAwesome"}"">';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the single quotation mark at

```
data-iconsets='{"fa"
```

that ends the string and PHP doesn't know what the following { is.